# Блок-ссылка и ссылки внутри него

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок, при нажатии на который (onclick) браузер перенаправляется на новую страницу - некая имитация ссылки. То есть, "ссылкой" является весь блок со всем своим содержимым. Появилась необходимость разместить внутри этого блока другую ссылку (`<a href...>...</a>`).

То есть, при нажатии в любое место блока браузер должен перенаправляться на одну страницу, но если внутри этого блока мы нажали на ссылку `<a>`, браузер должен переходить по ссылке внутри этого тега, а не по общей ссылке блока. Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
  $('document').ready(function() {
    $('.block').on('click', function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).hasClass('link')) {
        alert('Block clicked');
        return;
      }

      alert('Link clicked');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid;">
  <p>Test</p>
  <a class="link" href="#">I'm link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Немного доработал, чтобы не было привязано к классу (не у всех ссылок есть классы): http://jsfiddle.net/kjh32kd3/

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать немного удобнее.

1. Как известно в JQuery у объекта события есть два полезных свойства:
   target - непосредственно тот элемент, из-за которого было вызвано
   событие и currentTarget - элемент на который повешен обработчик
   этого события
2. Добавим в элементы при нажатии на которые будет происходить переход атрибут data-href, 
       показывающий url страницы для перехода.
3. При вызове события в обработчике будем проверять, есть
       ли у элемента вызвавшего событие аттрибут data-href, если есть берем урл
       из этого атрибута и переходим по нему, если же нет, тогда берем урл
       из главного блока.

http://jsfiddle.net/8542medo/

```js
$('.b-block').on('click', function(evt) {
  var href = evt.target.hasAttribute('data-href') ?
    evt.target.getAttribute('data-href') :
    evt.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-href');

  alert(href) // А после совершаем переход по ссылке
});
```

```css
.b-block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-block" data-href="#first">
  <a href="#" data-href="#second">I'm link</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```